# Setting and Getting variables within a subscribe method

Tags: angular

I was just starting to learn Angular, but I'm kind of confused with how to get this to work in the following scenario. Assume that the response in service.ts returns a number other than 0 (i.e. a custom error message should be set):

service.ts

```
errorMessage: string = "";

setErrorMessage(message:string){
    this.errorMessage = message;
}

getErrorMessage(){
    return this.errorMessage;
}

setRegistrationData(provider, email){
   this.login.accountExist(provider, email).subscribe( (response: UserCount) => {
      if (response.count == 0) {
         //do something
         return true;
      }else{
         this.setErrorMessage("Custom Error Message");
         return false;
      }
}
```

component.ts

```
  errorMessage = "";

  sendData(){
    if(this.register.setRegistrationData(provider, email)){
      //do something
    }else{
      this.errorMessage = this.service.getErrorMessage();
      console.log(this.errorMessage); //Empty
      console.log(this.service.getErrorMessage()); //Empty
      console.log("Catastrophic Failure");
    }
  }
```

component.html

```
<input type="submit" (click)="sendData();" />
<div>{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

So I understand that the setting of the errorMessage in service.ts is completed after the getting of the errorMessage in component.ts as a result of the subscribe method. This was tested via the console logs which gave two empty lines before printing "Catastrophic Error".

What is the best way of getting that Custom Error Message across to the template?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When the number is different than 0, is the status of the response different than a success ?

Comment: Not quite sure as to what you mean. Let's say that the response outputs a value of {count: 1}, then, it sets the errorMessage in service as "Custom Error Message" at that point of time. And then it returns false. Could you clarify further please?

Comment: I was talking about the http status, but that seems to not be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thinking about what I was trying to achieve, I simply moved the subscribe aspect over to component.ts and let component.ts handle anything to do with error messages which solves the whole thing.

Essentially, service.ts should perform and return the HTTP request with component.ts subscribing to it and handling the logic.